# What is this plant with narrow leaves at the edge of my flower bed?

Tags: identification

Does anyone know what this plant is that is popping up near my pansies and daylillies?

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you told us where in the world those pansies and daylilies are. Thanks!

Comment: They are in New Jersey.

Comment: So how do they look now?

Answer (score 1):

A very "stab-in-the-dark" answer would be emerging leaves of a kind of asteracea - one of the coneflower varieties rudbecia / echinacea / ratabida, just going by leaf shape and structure.

Let them grow a bit more, wait for flowers and update your post and I can either confirm or remove this answer.

Comment: Did you mean ein Schuss ins Blaue?  :)

Comment: @kevinsky - keeping tabs, eh? Sure I did!

Comment: Or "educated guess"-ish ^_^